# How to filter DateTime(intl) in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, intl

I have list of data and I want to filter them from earliest to lates

The list with data looks like this:

```
[{id: 73, startTime: 2022-12-13T15:30:57.244Z}, {id: 74, startTime: 2022-12-13T10:00:57.244Z}];
```

And the output should look like this:

```
[{id: 74, startTime: 2022-12-13T10:00:57.244Z}, {id: 73, startTime: 2022-12-13T15:30:57.244Z}];
```

How can I do this? P.S. I am using intl

Comment: where do you use intl package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say we have this list:

```
List dateList = [
    {"id": 73, "startTime": "2022-12-13T15:30:57.244Z"},
    {"id": 74, "startTime": "2022-12-13T10:00:57.244Z"},
  ];
```

you can use `sort()` like this:

```
dateList.sort((a, b) => a["startTime"].compareTo(b["startTime"]));
```

result:

```
[
   {id: 74, startTime: 2022-12-13T10:00:57.244Z},
   {id: 73, startTime: 2022-12-13T15:30:57.244Z}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like:

```
 var parsedList = [
    {'id': 73, 'startTime': '2022-12-13T15:30:57.244Z'},
    {'id': 74, 'startTime': '2022-12-13T10:00:57.244Z'}
  ];

  parsedList.sort((a, b) => DateTime.parse(a['startTime'].toString())
      .compareTo(DateTime.parse(b['startTime'].toString())));
```